# I can't get node.js mysql INSERT INTO statement to work

Tags: javascript, mysql, express

I am developing a small apt bldg mgmt app using node.js, Express and mySQL. It is 90% completed.

In the function to add a new resident, I am using the new resident form inputs name, pwd, block#, apt#, monthly apt maintenance fee, passed to the function as variable parameters, to set the 'isim', 'sifre', 'blokno', 'daireno', 'aylik_aidat' columns respectively in the mysql table 'havuzs_sakinleri'. For the rest of the column values, I am using the current year from mySQL and numeric constants. When I run the app, I get the following error message and output at the console.

> code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
> errno: 1064,
> sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Meydaner, 2222, 1, 6, 2021, 225, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0,' at line 1",
> sqlState: '42000',
> index: 0,
> sql: 'INSERT INTO havuzs_sakinleri (isim, sifre, blokno, daireno, yil, aylik_aidat, ay1_no, ay1_odemesi, ay2_no, ay2_odemesi, ay3_no, ay3_odemesi, ay4_no, ay4_odemesi, ay5_no, ay5_odemesi, ay6_no, ay6_odemesi, ay7_no, ay7_odemesi, ay8_no, ay8_odemesi, ay9_no, ay9_odemesi, ay10_no, ay10_odemesi, ay11_no, ay11_odemesi, ay12_no, ay12_odemesi, toplam_odenen_tl, devredilen_tl, aidat_bakiye) VALUES(Behran Meydaner, 2222, 1, 6, 2021, 225, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0, 10, 0, 11, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0)'

}

As can be seen from the output, mySQL substitutes all column values with the values from the VALUES clause, correctly. But for some reason, it doesn't like something about the first value '+usrname+', in the VALUES clause. I have checked the syntax over and over again but I can't find anything wrong. The interesting thing is that if I use a string literal enclosed in double quotes as "Behran Meydaner", it works but if I use '+usrname+' as value it doesn't work. It accepts all other '+.....+' values but somehow it doesn't like the first value '+usrname+'. usrname is a valid input from the input form. If someone can tell me what is wrong with this, I will appreciate it. Thanks.

The javaScript function in question is below.

```
function addUser(usrname, usrpwd, usrblokno, usrdaireno, usraidat, callback) {
    var today    = new Date();
    var curryear = today.getFullYear();
    var sql      = 'INSERT INTO havuzs_sakinleri (isim, sifre, blokno, daireno, yil, aylik_aidat, ' +
                'ay1_no, ay1_odemesi, ay2_no, ay2_odemesi, ay3_no, ay3_odemesi, ay4_no, ay4_odemesi, ' +
                'ay5_no, ay5_odemesi, ay6_no, ay6_odemesi, ay7_no, ay7_odemesi, ay8_no, ay8_odemesi, ' +
                'ay9_no, ay9_odemesi, ay10_no, ay10_odemesi, ay11_no, ay11_odemesi, ay12_no, ay12_odemesi, ' +
                'toplam_odenen_tl, devredilen_tl, aidat_bakiye) ' +
                'VALUES('+usrname+', '+usrpwd+', '+usrblokno+', '+usrdaireno+', '+curryear+', '+usraidat+', ' +
                '1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0, 10, 0, 11, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0)';
    con.query( sql, function( err, res ){
        if ( err ) { // If error in adding new user to the database, display error message.
            throw err;
            status_message=('Site sakini eklenirken sorun oluştu.');
        }
        else  // If add is successful, display a message.
            status_message = ("Bu kisi yeni site sakini olarak veri tabanina eklendi. Ana sayfaya dönmek için lütfen Ana sayfa butonuna tıklayınız!");

        return callback( status_message );
    } );
}
```

Comment: String type values must be quoted  `'Behran Meydaner'`  `(\''+usrname+'\',`

Comment: Your code is open for SQL injection. You should use [prepared statements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#preparing-queries). You should never write such code, even if this is only for learning purposes.

Comment: Yes , I have read a lot of comments about sql injection and the alternatives but the all the alternatives were confusing and not easy to understand. I am using js, Express and mySQl and I don't want to introduce another middleware unless I have to. So, is there an easy way to use prepared statements and if  so how?

Comment: Yes, I posted a link in my comment. You should read about [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Thanks jabaa. Following your advise, I have changed my sql statement as follows to escape query values.

Comment: var sql = 'INSERT INTO havuzs_sakinleri (isim, sifre, blokno, daireno, yil, aylik_aidat, ay1_odemesi, ay2_odemesi, ay3_odemesi, ay4_odemesi, ay5_odemesi, ay6_odemesi, ay7_odemesi, ay8_odemesi, ay9_odemesi, ay10_odemesi, ay11_odemesi, ay12_odemesi, toplam_odenen_tl, devredilen_tl, aidat_bakiye) VALUES ?';
var values = [usrname, usrpwd, usrblokno, usrdaireno, curryear, usraidat, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0];           
con.query(sql, [values], function(err,res)  {

Comment: However, mySQL still complains about the 1st value usrname variable because it has a character string. please tell me how to code it. thx.

Comment: I got it. I needed to code the values as:      var values = [[usrname, usrpwd, usrblokno, usrdaireno, curryear, usraidat, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]];